# Regex vba script throwing error : runtime error 9 ... Subscript out of range

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word doc with some numbers referred in the foot notes. and I am exporting these references as a csv file.

```
Sub FindNumber()
Dim exp, exp1 As RegExp
Set exp = New RegExp
exp.Pattern = "\b[A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{7}\b"
exp.Global = True

Dim splits(1000) As String
Dim x As Long

Dim results As MatchCollection
Set results = exp.Execute(ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdFootnotesStory))
x = 1

For Each res In results
splits(x) = res
x = x + 1
Next res


Dim Filename As String, line As String
Dim i As Integer
Filename = "C:\VBA Export" & "\Numbers.csv"
Open Filename For Output As #2
Print #2, "Control Numbers"
For i = LBound(splits) To UBound(splits)

Print #2, splits(i)

Next i
Close #2
MsgBox "Numbers were exported to " & Filename, vbInformation
End Sub
```

The code above was working fine and just suddenly starting throwing error at 'splits(x) = res'
I have tried checking my regex and I can see that it works fine. If I change splits(x) to splits(6) or something similar it works like a charm .

Can someone please help ?

Comment: When it fails, what's the value of `x` ?  Why not write each value of `res` directly to the file though?  There's no real need for `splits()`.

Comment: Hi Tim, 1001 is the value of x, while my document should have around 500-600 references that i am looking for

Comment: So either make your array larger, swap it out for a `Collection`, or write the results directly to the file.

Comment: How would i write it directly to a file ? Sorry in a noob at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** - changed code to write matches directly to Excel.

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim oXl As Excel.Application 'add reference to MS Excel object library...
    Dim oWb As Excel.Workbook, c As Excel.Range, i As Long, col As Collection
    
    Set oXl = New Excel.Application
    oXl.Visible = True
    Set oWb = oXl.Workbooks.Add()
    Set c = oWb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
    
    ListMatchesInExcel ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdFootnotesStory), _
                       "\b[A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{7}\b", _
                       "Id Numbers", c
    Set c = c.Offset(0, 1)
                    
    ListMatchesInExcel ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdFootnotesStory), _
                    "\b[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{9}\b", _
                    "Other Numbers", c
    Set c = c.Offset(0, 1)
    
    'etc etc
End Sub

'Search through `SearchText` for text matching `patt` and export all
'  matches to Excel with a header `HeaderText`, starting at range `c`
Sub ListMatchesInExcel(SearchText As String, patt As String, _
                     headerText As String, c As Excel.Range)
    'add reference to MicroSoft VBscript regular expressions
    Dim exp, exp1 As RegExp, col As New Collection
    Dim results As MatchCollection, res As Match, i As Long
    
    Set exp = New RegExp
    exp.Pattern = patt
    exp.Global = True
    Set results = exp.Execute(SearchText)
    'log to Immediate pane
    Debug.Print (col.Count - 1) & " matche(s) for '" & patt & "'"
    c.Value = headerText
    i = 1
    For Each res In results
        c.Offset(i).Value = res
        i = i + 1
    Next res
    c.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great! also I suggested couple edits in the declarations to avoid compilation errors

Comment: Also I have the same script running for multiple regex expressions. can we print these out as their own columns ?

Comment: In different files, or as new columns in the same file?

Comment: In the same file please :)

Comment: I don't see how you'd organize the file though?  Wouldn't different patterns give different numbers of hits?

Comment: I was thinking Column A- pattern 1 , Column B - Pattern 2 etc .

Comment: What would you do with the output file? Open it in excel?

Comment: Yes, just excel use.

Comment: OK - see edit above.

Comment: Thanks i have added the VB expressions v1.0 and 5.5 but still doesnt define the excel.range as variable. any tips ?

Comment: See the first comment in Sub `Tester`

Comment: Sweet yea thats perfect ! Cheers :)